# Enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) in Azure WebRoles

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, azure

How can I turn on HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) for Azure WebRoles?

Comment: What is your project? MVC? Web-forms?

Comment: have a look on my recent write-up http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/02/implemnting-https-everywhere-in-asp-net-mvc-application/  might be helpful for your goals.

Comment: This solution conflict with the HSTS specs. Review section 7.2 http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6797#section-7.2

Comment: HSTS specs. section 7.2 says:
If an HSTS Host receives an HTTP request message over a non-secure
transport, it SHOULD send an HTTP response message containing a
status code indicating a permanent redirect, such as status code 301.

Comment: So you are after a redirecting filter that sends 301 for non secure requests? If you include these details, perhaps it would be easier to get an answer, rather than point people to RFC

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/417173/enable-http-strict-transport-security-hsts-in-iis-7

Answer (score 31):

The accepted answer is confusing and the [correct answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/417173/enable-http-strict-transport-security-hsts-in-iis-7) (on ServerFault) is hidden in the comments, so I'll just recap it quickly here. Basically this is what you want to do:

1. Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
2. Add the `Strict-Transport-Security` header to all HTTPS requests

The appropriate web.config would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"
                        redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security"
                        pattern=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
                </rule>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you want to comply with [HSTS preload](https://hstspreload.appspot.com/) you'll need `includeSubDomains` and `preload` in the `Strict_Transport_Security` header too. Here's my full rewrite configuration, including apex redirection (I'm a [yes-www](http://www.yes-www.org/) guy) and easy local development setup (no HTTPS on localhost):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="^localhost$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yourdomain\.com" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.yourdomain.com/{R:1}" 
           redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="HSTS" enabled="true">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Of course, switch `yourdomain` with your actual domain.

Comment: Consider adding `includeSubDomains` https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @et I'm already using it... look at the full rewrite configuration at the bottom.

Comment: Is there a way to make this return 308 instead of 301? I have API clients sending POST requests and sending a 301 causes them to use a GET to the alternate address instead of a POST (which doesn't work since I never see the original POST to process). My understanding is 308 implies 'keep verb' AND permanent redirect (as opposed to temporary), but I can't see how to do that with the url rewrite.

Comment: @Yort looks like you're out of luck: `redirectType` – Specifies the status code to use during redirect: 301 – Permanent, 302 – Found, 303 – See other, 307 – Temporary (https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference).

Comment: That's what I feared. Thanks for confirming. I may need to resort to a custom asp.net filter in my app I guess. Shame, I liked this solution.

Comment: Great solution. I'm using it on an Azure App Service and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. If we want to use this for a site on a subdomain (e.g. `shop.mysite.com`) do I simply remove the `Redirect to www` rule?

Comment: @Jake not necessarily, that rules would only redirect anything that starts with `mysite.com` to `www.mysite.com`. Hence, `shop.mysite.com` (or any other subdomain) would not be affected.

Comment: @OhadSchneider This is pretty much what I have implemented, but am having an issue with the fact I don't know the domain and that I need to make sure I don't redirect subdomains to the www version.  I've tried to explain on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910233/iis-url-rewrite-rules-www-ssl-web-config Any chance you can advise?

Comment: This solution requires an IIS extension: the URL Rewrite Module https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module.

Answer (score 8):

There is an IIS module which enables HSTS compliant with the HSTS Draft Specification (RFC 6797); you can found it here https://hstsiis.codeplex.com/

**DON'T TRY THIS:**

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"/>
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

**because this will include the STS header in HTTP responses over non-secure transport.**

Comment: Then, how DO you install it? Can I install the HSTS-IIS-Module-2.0.0.msi file in Azure? Or do I copy the .dlls to my bin folder for my ASP.NET MVC 5 application?