# IIS Url Rewrite Rules - www/SSL - web.config

Tags: ssl, redirect, iis, iis-7, web-config

I am trying to write some rewrite rules in the `<system.webServer>` section of the web.config file.

My aim is that any url missing the `www` section would be rewritten as `www.myurl.com`.  I believe that this should actually be a 301 redirect? To add to this, I also want to make sure that I am using SSL with HSTS.

I need to make sure that I don't fix this rule to a single domain, for example, it needs to work for `foo.com` and `bar.com` along with any others that I might choose to support in the future (there could be quite a few when I start looking at country specific domains).

Here is what I have so far:

```xml
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Non WWW redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www|office365|bdf01)\." negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The above has 3 rules:
- HTTP to HTTPS
- Non-WWW to WWW
- HSTS

It looks as though my HTTP-HTTPS rule is working fine, but that is the only one.

The non-www redirect needs to be able to allow specific sub-domains.  THe example above should not add the www. to the url's of office365.foo.com or bdf01.foo.com **This part doesn't work** - See example 1.

I'm not certain how best to test HSTS, but I am using a website called [woorank](http://www.woorank.com) to review the website and it says that HSTS is not enabled. **Not sure if this is working, but appears not**

I'm not really sure how the pattern matching works within these rules, so would be more than happy for links to resources that can help me understand this part better.  Any help would be gratefully appreciated

**Example 1**

When I go to the home page of `http://foo.com`, I should be taken to `https://www.foo.com`, instead I am taken to `https://foo.com`.  Likewise, If I navigate to `http://office365.foo.com` I should actually get `https://office365.foo.com` but I still get the same `http://` address.

Comment: The following is possibly similar, but I believe it removes www, and does not deal with the sub domains or HSTS. Also, why does it use {CACHE_URL} https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511871/web-config-url-rewrites-https-and-non-www

Comment: Can you be more specific about "doesn't work" and "not sure if this is working"? What is happening exactly in each case? As for resources, start with the homepage: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite. What you need is probably in the configuration reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference.

Comment: @OhadSchneider Thanks for the reply - I have added an example above to explain what I am expecting to see in the "doesn't work" section as this is my main issue.  I'll have a look through the resources you gave now to see what else I can work out.  Thanks

Comment: Cool, please update here on what you find. This handy tool can help you make sure your regex expressions are doing what you want them to do: https://regex101.com/.

Comment: FYI: I hit the same issue, though I was doing my subdomain forwarding at DNS level.  Related post here: https://serverfault.com/questions/900913/using-hsts-with-sub-domain-forwarding.

Comment: Regarding your first example, I think the reason you're going from `http://foo.com` to `https://foo.com` but no further is the `HTTP to HTTPS redirect` rule's `stopProcessing` attribute is set to `true`.