# Azure HSTS security on ports 454 and 455

Tags: asp.net, azure, security, pci-compliance, hsts

I'm working with a client on their Azure instance to get them PCI compliant.  Scans from BeyondSecurity.com continue to come back with

- HSTS Missing From HTTPS Server [site.com:454]
- HSTS Missing From HTTPS Server [site.com:455]

I've already implemented a general HSTS security based on this post: [Enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) in Azure WebRoles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887524/enable-http-strict-transport-security-hsts-in-azure-webroles).  It's this past part with the 2 ports that, from what I can tell, are some kind of communication port that Azure uses between it's instances.

What can I do to help get these ports to pass the scans?  I've seen some stuff about TLS 1.2 fixing this, but I can't find anything to confirm this.